# What does this question mark mean in Flow: "?() => void"

Tags: javascript, flowtype

In a [GitHub project](https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app/blob/b5df451259897d1838933f01ad4596784325c2ad/js/store/configureStore.js#L47-L47) I recently saw this function declaration:

```
function configureStore(onComplete: ?() => void) {
```

What this question mark is about?

I guess, `onComplete` is named parameter, getting function calls. And the question mark is stating that this parameter could be optional and will default to "void", which would mean the same like a nil/null pointer what means "no closure" assigned here.

Am I right?

Comment: No; that's a type.

Comment: Can you explain it a litte more to me pls? (or send a link to docs; i already search at google but did not find anything about)

Comment: I guess it's either flow or typescript. http://flowtype.org/, https://www.typescriptlang.org/

Comment: `?` indicates that this is Flow [nullable type](http://flowtype.org/docs/nullable-types.html) and not TypeScript.

Comment: I just added the URL to the github project. And here also: https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app/blob/b5df451259897d1838933f01ad4596784325c2ad/js/store/configureStore.js#L47-L47

Comment: If it's from Facebook, it's flow ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Almost.

`() => void` is Flow's annotation for a function that returns nothing (`undefined`, aka `void 0`).

The leading question mark in `?MyType` is Flow's way of expressing a nullable type.

So in this case `configureStore` accepts one argument called `onComplete` that must be either null or a function that returns nothing.

Flow will not add a default value for `onComplete` or coerce it in any way because unlike typescript, Flow does not generate any new JS code. At runtime, all Flow annotations are stripped to get vanilla JS, and that's that.